# how to eliminet same data Table View When get data using NSXMlParsing

Tags: iphone

XML Categary tag is same data For me i got twice in table View please give me reply fast.

if in application xml some data are repeat like if we have recipe Many of recipe belongs same landmark so for in my app that all are show repeatedly in table view i want to element same name in xmL (i want to group by them).

Thank you my friend in advance

Comment: I cant understand your XML file.. Could you be more specific by providing some of your code.

Comment: i still not get proper way for this that`s why i start use database and than using group by query i done this..... if other way is their than said me......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Repeated Data i use database, in database i add all parsing data from webservices, than using Group by query make differentiate same data.